# Why does it takes so long for OpenCV to capture frames and store them in memory?

Tags: c++, opencv

So, I'm writing a program that loads a video in memory to determine if it's unstabilized. I realized the program was taking way too long to execute, so I put a timer on my code:

```
const clock_t begin = std::clock();

int frame_count = 0;
bool should_stop = false;

std::vector <cv::Mat> frames;

while(!should_stop)
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;

    frames.push_back(frame.clone());

    if (frame.empty())
    {
        should_stop = true;
        continue;
    }
    frame_count++;
}

std::cout << "Time: " << float( std::clock () - begin ) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
```

But then, the timer prints measures around ~0.70s (fairly enough for ~200 frames) as opposed as what I observe and measure with the `time` command:

```
$ time ./program ~/Desktop/video.mp4
Time: 0.700728s
./program ~/Desktop/video.mp4  0,56s user 0,19s system 2% cpu 36,409 total
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?